# SQL DATEDIFF with MILLISECONDS on SubSelect

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I wonder why you can not use `DATEDIFF` with `MILLISECONDS` on SubSelect.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM vrghmdemo.dbo.xrmQueues
    WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, CreateDateTime, GETDATE()) < 2
) sub
WHERE DATEDIFF(MS, CreateDateTime, GETDATE()) < 500
```

This leads to (german):

> Meldung 535: Die datediff-Funktion führte zu einem Überlauf. Die Anzahl von datepart-Werten, die zwei Datums-/Uhrzeitinstanzen trennen, ist zu groß.

(English equivalent):

> The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart.

If I use the same `WHERE` condition outside the SubSelect again it works.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM vrghmdemo.dbo.xrmQueues
    WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, CreateDateTime, GETDATE()) < 2
) sub
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, CreateDateTime, GETDATE()) < 2
    AND DATEDIFF(MS, CreateDateTime, GETDATE()) < 500
```

Why is that so? The Condition is used already in the SubSelect.

Comment: If you are using `SQL Server 2016` try `DATEDIFF_BIG` - http://blog.devart.com/sql-server-2016-ctp3-1-whats-new-for-developer.html

Comment: Can you supply a sample date that fails?

Answer (score 6):

Instead of computing a `DATEDIFF` in milliseconds, instead change the target for comparison:

```
select * from vrghmdemo.dbo.xrmQueues
where DATEADD(millisecond, -500, GetDate()) <= CreatedDateTime
```

Which also, handily, also would allow an index (on `CreatedDateTime`, if such an index exists) to be used.

---

The reason for the error is because SQL Server freely moves calculations around, to where they're most efficiently calculated. In this case, it's decided to evaluate your outer `DATEDIFF` calculation as its scanning the base table, and before it considers the predicate within the subquery.

Comment: This method has the added advantages of being [SARGable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) and requiring SQL Server to only execute the DATEADD() function one time instead of executing the DATEDIFF() function at least once for every row.

Answer (score 0):

[DATEDIFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms189794.aspx) returns an [INTEGER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187745.aspx), which can hold any value from -2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647).  If the number of milliseconds exceeds this you will encounter the overflow error.

SQL Server 2016 and Azure include the function [DATEDIFF_BIG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/mt628058.aspx) which returns a [BIGINT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187745.aspx).  This time you are limited to values between -2^63 (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808) and 2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807).  If the number of milliseconds exceeds these limits you cannot use this function either.

**EDIT:** I've removed the section below.  As pointed out by  Damien_The_Unbeliever this is incorrect.

> Your 2nd query prevents the overflow by ensuring only records with a
>   day diff of 2 are calculated, which keeps you within the INT limits.

Comment: Neither query is guaranteed to error nor guaranteed to *not* error. We're entirely at the mercy of the optimizer here, there's no guarantee of order of evaluation in SQL.